# I am able to receive mails but unable to send via my SMTP server?

Tags: email, smtp, spf, dkim

I have a shared hosting server from hostgator, in which I created an email 'support@mydomain.com'. Then I enabled both DKIM and SPF (as I read on a few threads that SPF should be enabled to ensure a trusted SMTP server). I have no idea about configuring the SPF (I did read about it but could not get anywhere).

The issue is, when I login with my 'support@mydomain.com' credentials to any mail client (e.g. SquirrelMail), I am able to receive mails on this email address, but when I try to send mail to some email address (e.g. myemailaddress@gmail.com), it bounces back the following message.

=================================

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  myemailaddress@gmail.com
    This message from "support" <support@mydomain.com> [support@mydomain.com], Subject:
    test , with RefID:
str=0001.0A150208.54EB188D.00DF,ss=4,sh,re=0.001,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,cl=4,cld=1,fgs=8
was rejected due to classification as CONFIRMED SPAM.

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <support@mydomain.com>
Received: from mailnull by md-in-20.webhostbox.net with sa-checked (Exim 4.84)
        (envelope-from <support@mydomain.com>)
        id 1YPuQv-002m7L-O7
        for myemailaddress@gmail.com; Mon, 23 Feb 2015 14:56:29 +0000
Received: from localhost ([::1]:49427 helo=mydomain.com)
        by md-in-20.webhostbox.net with esmtpa (Exim 4.84)
        (envelope-from <support@mydomain.com>)
        id 1YPuQv-002m7D-Hx
        for myemailaddress@gmail.com; Mon, 23 Feb 2015 14:56:29 +0000
Received: from 223.176.159.62 ([223.176.159.62])
        (SquirrelMail authenticated user support@mydomain.com)
        by mydomain.com with HTTP;
        Mon, 23 Feb 2015 14:56:29 -0000
Message-ID: <f453beb71a8ea02558b450eadff10f78.squirrel@mydomain.com>
Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 14:56:29 -0000
Subject: test
From: "support" <support@mydomain.com>
To: myemailaddress@gmail.com
User-Agent: SquirrelMail/1.5.2 [SVN]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Authenticated_sender: support@mydomain.com
X-OutGoing-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.0
X-Spam-Checker-Version: spamc_ctasd client on
        localost
X-Spam-Level: **********
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=100.0 required=50.0 tests=SpamClass_Confirmed,
        VirusClass_Unknown autolearn=disabled
        version=1.0.0
X-CTCH-PVer: 0000001
X-CTCH-Spam: Confirmed
X-CTCH-VOD: Unknown
X-CTCH-Flags: 8
X-CTCH-RefID:
str=0001.0A150208.54EB188D.00DF,ss=4,sh,re=0.001,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,cl=4,cld=1,fgs=8
X-CTCH-Score: 0.001
X-CTCH-ScoreCust: 0.000
X-CTCH-Rules: C_4847,
X-CTCH-SenderID: support@mydomain.com
X-CTCH-SenderID-Flags: 8192
X-CTCH-SenderID-TotalMessages: 2
X-CTCH-SenderID-TotalSpam: 0
X-CTCH-SenderID-TotalSuspected: 0
X-CTCH-SenderID-TotalConfirmed: 2
X-CTCH-SenderID-TotalBulk: 0
X-CTCH-SenderID-TotalVirus: 0
X-CTCH-SenderID-TotalRecipients: 0

this is a test mail
```

=================================

Am I missing something in configuring DKIM or SPF ? Or do I have to wait for some time after configuring SPF ?

I am working with SPF for the first time, so I would be a great help to show me path about how to configure this SPF thing.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue here is SPF. You need to designate your hosting IP as a permitted sender of email for your domain when you have SPF on. You would do this from your domain registrar. Create a new TXT record to add your IP as a permitted sender.

TXT mydomain.com "v=spf1 ip4:192.168.0.x mx -all"

Where the 192.168.0.x is replaced with your hosting IP.

See http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax

Incidentally, your post was probably downvoted (not by me) because this answer is very likely to have been answered already, as most SPAM-related issues have.

UPDATE: Since I can't add a comment (I don't have 50 reputation), I'm glad you got it resolved (and thanks for the upvote). Perhaps the reason the email was deemed suspicious is that your IP isn't a "trusted sender" for the domain. Often, that will add to the SPAM rating if not outright flag the email from some providers. Just a thought in case this happens again. Until you add the IP as a trusted sender, it possible some recipients of your emails will mark them as SPAM as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aaron. I did search on web about this issue, and tried all solutions that people provided on different websites, without any luck. I finally got it resolved, and have added an answer to the question.
+1 for not down-voting and trying to help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I contacted my hosting provider to help me resolve the issue. For those who are seeking answer for similar issue, I suggest to contact their hosting provider. In my case, this was the reply from hostgator (my hosting provider).

> "The mails were being blocked due to Commtouch blacklisting as the
>   mail patterns were considered suspcious by Commtouch. We have
>   whitelisted your mail pattern and it may take next one hour to unblock
>   the domain from the blacklist. Please check your mailing service after
>   an hour."

I have no idea what they were talking about, as I am not a server guy, but I got my issue resolved. :)